# What is the difference between Block and Module?

Tags: functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)

I don't understand the difference between the Matheamtica functions `Block` and `Module`.  They seem to do the same thing: they both allow the definition of local variables.

Comment: While it may be a duplicate, this is a great way to ask the question that many new users have.

Comment: @JoelKlein I agree. This is why it is best to close this a a dupe, but not delete it, so it will serve as a pointer to the other one.

Comment: @JoelKlein Leonid is correct. A unique way into a problem is often welcome, so likely it won't be deleted. (This improves its searchability, too.) But, it should be closed so effort is not duplicated between the two.